# Webmaster API v3: getting servingLimitExceeded using batch requests

Tags: google-api, google-search-console, google-api-ruby-client

I'm getting the `servingLimitExceeded` error message for results within batch but not for an entire batch. For example, I may get 100 records responding with this error and then it starts returning more results. All within the a single batch.

If batches are handled internally by Google API, how can I adjust them to not hit the rate limit? I tried adding a 1-second delay between batches but that doesn't change this. I also set `retries = 3` on the Ruby client, but I don't know if that means it retries a failed batch. I don't think it's retrying individual API calls within the batch, because the back-off should resolve this.

Do I have to record the failed results and create a new batch to recover those separately?

Incidentally, the [documented quota limit errors](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/errors#FORBIDDEN) are confusing. There are `dailyLimitExceeded` and `rateLimitExceeded` messages but this isn't returning one of those. The `servingLimitExceeded` description of "The overall rate limit specified for the API has already been reached" is not all that helpful but I'm *assuming* this is the rate limit that we hit.

**Update**

Looking at the code, I see that the retries in the ruby `google-api-client` only apply to [transmission](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/lib/google/api_client.rb#L637) and [authorization](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/lib/google/api_client.rb#L646) (401) errors. A 403 (which is what rate limit returns) [raises a `ClientError`](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/lib/google/api_client.rb#L661-L662) which is not retried anyway.

So setting `retries` on the client object has no bearing on this.

Is there something I can do to address this in the batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We received word from Webmaster team that the API is limited to 20QPS and there is currently no way to go higher.

One suggested solution is to [make smaller batch requests](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/210#issuecomment-100377192).

Comment: From empirical data, it appears that the new Search Analytics part of the Webmaster / Search Console API is actually limited to about 3QPS per account. Otherwise you get "Quota exceeded" errors, even though it's not related to quota.