# YouTube Data API - "Serving Limit Exceeded"

Tags: youtube-api

Over the past 24 hours we had a large number of [TubePress](http://tubepress.com/) users report an error message from YouTube:

```
Serving Limit Exceeded
```

Most of our users have their own Google API Key, and our cloud-hosted TubePress installation isn't anywhere close to hitting the daily quota. I can't find any documentation on this particular error message, nor can I understand why it would suddenly present itself on so many sites with different keys.

Could anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Tasks API: 403 Forbidden, Serving Limit Exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425384/google-tasks-api-403-forbidden-serving-limit-exceeded)

Comment: docs are here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/core_errors

Comment: Thanks for the link! Unfortunately for this particular error it's just way too vague: `The overall rate limit specified for the API has already been reached.`

Comment: same here http://stackoverflow.com/q/32470396/2432781

Comment: I've just [filed a bug report with YouTube](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7539). Please "star" that issue to draw attention to it and track updates, if you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

Even the reason of failure is about quota, it has nothing to do with the quota because the default limit is largely enough. The problem is the new Youtube anti-spam algorithm deployed at the end of last month. Unfortunately it impacts negatively on the normal users.

Comment: Interesting theory. How do you know it's related?

Comment: from personal experience...I think the new algo uses an internal quota limit which does not reflect the limit you see on the developper console, that's why you have both 403 errors ServingLimitUsage or QuotaExcedeed, so twisting this limit will not help. It does not impact every account, only account which trigger some "suspicious spam activity", so the appropriate question is more how to avoid the latter imo ? personally I think their new algo is too strict...

Comment: I assumed it must be something like this too. I haven't had either error for the last 3 days, so hoping they have relaxed something...

Comment: I haven't seen those errors for about a week - looks like they've fixed the issue

Comment: I don't think it was an issue, I think they adjust the anti-spam algo to relax alittle bit. I did see them do it in the past.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because your "Per-user limit" is set too low. You can up it by going to `Google Developer console` -> `APIs` -> `Enabled APIs` -> `<the API that's causing you trouble>` -> `Quotas` and set "Per user limit" higher.

Comment: Thanks your input. The default for the YouTube Data API seems to be 3,000 requests per second and 80M requests per day. We have many customers with low-traffic websites that are hitting this error after contacting the API maybe a few hundred times in an entire day, so I still feel that the problem is on YouTube's end..

Comment: I started to get the same error 10 days ago and it hasn't stopped. I will open a ticket for youtube, because the thing worked perfectly for the last couple of months (no changes made).

Comment: I've started getting quite a few of these errors recently too. I've added in the quotaUser query parameter passing an identified, but still get the odd error. I'm no-where near the 50M overall limit, and the per-user limit is maxed out at 3,000 requests per second and I've taken steps to stop this being exceeded.

I can only assume the problem is at YouTube's end, so in that sense I'm pleased to see others experiencing the same.. please keep us updated