# Hitting YouTube API serving limit with the slightest load

Tags: parse-platform, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a script at parse.com which imports a fresh information about recent videos from ~10 channels with YouTube v3 API. It worked well for some time, but about a month ago it started to fail once or twice per day with an error:

> Error: can't fetch https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/... "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "servingLimitExceeded", "message": "Serving Limit Exceeded" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Serving Limit Exceeded" }

As you can see from the following screenshot I use maximum 37k of 50000k units available per day. I estimate one script run could take maximum 2k units. To make absolutely sure I'm not hitting 3k units/second/user limit I've added 1 second delay before *every* call to YouTube API, but I still see those errors occasionally.

What's going on? Does YouTube v3 API have some other limits, for example units per IP? (one IP at Parse could host thousands of installations)

[image: google developer console screenshot]

Comment: Just got slightly different kind of error `403 quotaExceeded`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a issue on YouTube's end and doesn't seem related to the actual quota used.

I have been getting quite a few of these errors sporadically, and seemingly for no reason, over the last few weeks - see [YouTube Data API - “Serving Limit Exceeded”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32364990/youtube-data-api-serving-limit-exceeded#comment52840506_32438139)

Comment: I've been seeing this sporadically as well.

Comment: I haven't had any `403 servingLimitExceeded` errors since 11-Sep-2015 14:09:58 UTC or any `403 quotaExceeded` errors since 11-Sep-2015 14:38:21 UTC

Comment: I just got a few of those 403 servingLimitExceeded errors on my calls to the AdSense Management API over the last couple days. Logs show I only used about 200 queries per day, so am hoping this is just a temporary issue that Google is aware of and resolving.

Comment: Still no errors for me. I'm hoping they've sorted at least the YouTube Data API side of things. Will update if any change

Comment: Seems like they've fixed the issue

Comment: Yes, I haven't had any more unexpected 403 errors. Still get quite a few Error 500 / Backend Errors, which is what I'm guessing some the 403s we were seeing should have been?

Answer (score 2):

I've just [filed a bug report with YouTube](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7539). Please "star" that issue to draw attention to it and track updates, if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Version 3 of the YouTube Data API has concrete quota numbers listed in the Google API Console where you register for your API Key. You can use 30,000 units/second/user and 50,000,000 per day.

You can read about what a unit is [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).

A simple read operation that only retrieves the ID of each returned resource has a cost of approximately 1 unit.

A write operation has a cost of approximately 50 units.

A video upload has a cost of approximately 1600 units.

If you hit the limits, Google will stop returning results until your quota is reset. You can apply for more than 50M requests per day, but you will have to pay for those extra requests.

Also, you can read about why Google has deferred support to StackOverflow on their YouTube blog [here](https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow_14.html).

There are a number of active members on the YouTube Developer Relations team here including Jeff Posnick, Jarek Wilkiewicz, and Ibrahim Ulukaya who all have knowledge of YouTube internals...

Comment: Thanks Jagveer, but first, I see only 3k (not 30k you've mentioned) units/second/user limit on my console ([screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/rAUEptmV48JK)), and second, none of these answer the question, **why** I'm hitting the limit with only 2k units per hour load.